# Import .scss file into typescipt file in agnular app

Tags: angular, sass, nomachine-nx

I have `.scss` file. I imported it inside `.ts file` but the app can't get built.

I have `_export.scss` and `_export.scss.d.ts` files.

[image]

The error is;

> ./apps/appe/src/_export.scss:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
- ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

> :export {
> |   white: #fff;
> | }

× Failed to compile.

**`_export.scss` file;**

```css
:export {
  white: #fff;
}
```

***`appcomponent.ts` file;***

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import sassVariablesExport from '../_export.scss';

@Component({
  selector: 'qwe-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'appe';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let qweee = sassVariablesExport;
  }
}
```

[Github linke](https://github.com/muratcanoguzhan/sass-import-problem)